# how do I add a custom tab in my page?

Tags: facebook, tabs

The Dev App is different... Before it was very easy, just clicking "Add to my Page" link found in "App Profile Pages", now how do I add a custom tab in my page?

Comment: Where do you want to add tabs??

Answer (score 0):

Here's the new way to add a tab to a page:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/

For a user initiated action that you can embed on one of your pages.

```
<script> 
  FB.init({appId: "YOUR_APP_ID", status: true, cookie: true});

  function addToPage() {

    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'pagetab',
      redirect_uri: 'YOUR_URL',
    };

    FB.ui(obj);
  }

</script>
```

Or you can simply type this into your browser bar:

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID
&display=popup&next=YOUR_URL`

The YOUR_URL URL should be something from your app settings such as the site url.  It's just the next place the user will go once they add your app as a page tab.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=123456789&display=popup&next=https://www.facebook.com/MegaPet

Open a ERROR API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.     

I'm suspiciously that Facebook wants to eliminate all amateurs and work only with professional developers. All the tutorials available are outdated due to constant changes.
I can not believe that including a simple welcome tab to my fan page is so complicated.

Comment: THE_PAGE_TO_BE_ADDED_TO
It's the url of my fan page or url to my welcome tab?

Comment: I may have been mistaken about the `next=` parameter.  See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/  It should be a link to the site mentioned in the APP's settings instead of the page ... editing my answer above to reflect this new knowledge.